# Overflow:hidden; not working for nested div

Tags: html, css

Before you say anything, I looked, so I either missed the post like this or it's not a duplicate, keep in mind as this will seem similar problem to most overflow problems...

Okay, so my problem is that I have made a drop down navigation, of course it's using lists, floats to left and aligned it right....  I can use overflow:hidden on body, works on desktop fine but not mobile (of course I will change hover etc later to a javascript onclick for mobile), so I had an idea, nest it all in a div, set it to 100% width/height, should work in theory, right?  Well it did not, I have made a class to hide overflow, works on the div with the background for my navigation, but NOT in a separate div before the background navigation, code is below.

```css
/*gradient behind the navigation*/
#nav_grad {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffff00, #CCCC00); 
 position:absolute; 
 left:0%; 
 top:0%; 
 height:70px; 
 width:100%; 
 z-index:0; 
}

/*Navigation is indexed to be infront of background and the main content above^^^*/
.nav { 
 position:relative;
 left:60%;
 top:20%;
}

/*Removes margins and padding*/
ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

/*nav bar design*/
ul li {
 float: left; 
 width: 7%; 
 height: 40px; 
 opacity: 0.9; 
 line-height: 40px; 
 text-align: center; 
 font-size: 90%; 
 padding-right: 3%;
 padding-left: 3%;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*links design for nav bar*/
ul li a {
 text-decoration: none; 
 color: black;
 font-style: bold;
 font-weight: 800;
 display: block;
}
/*Text of drop navigation when you hover hover*/
ul li a:hover {
 color:#999999;
 opacity:1;
}

/*by default nothing will be displayed until you hover*/
ul li ul li{
 display: none;
}

/*Drop down when you hover*/
ul li:hover ul li {
 display: block;
 margin-left: -20%;
 width: 140%;
 background-color: #5555ff;
}

/*prevents overflow (WELL MEANT TO)*/
.nav_container {
 width:100%;
 height:70px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

/*When I hover the idea is to make the div so drop down can be seen on Y axis, still keeping overflow on the x*/
.nav_container:hover {
 height:100%;
}

/*creates a div in the center of the screen for all the content, indexed to be behind navigation bar but in front of the background*/
#content { 
 position:absolute; 
 left:25%; 
 top:15%; 
 height:84.4%; 
 width:50%; 
 background-color: #ffffff; 
 border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
 z-index:-1; 
 overflow: auto;
}

/*If screen is under 860 pixels below will happen*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 860px){
  .nav {
   position:relative;
  left:55%;
  top:20%;
  }
 
 ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -40%;
  width: 180%;
  background-color: #5555ff;
 }
    
  #nav_grad {
    background: linear-gradient(#ffff00, #CCCC00); 
   position:absolute; 
   left:0%; 
   top:0%; 
   height:50px; 
   width:100%; 
   z-index:0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="nav_container"> <!--Here is the div that should control drop down list overflow-->

 <!--Linear gradient div is behind navigation-->
 <div id="nav_grad" style="text-align:center;">
  <!--navigation-->
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Hover</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="one.html">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="two.html">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="three.html">Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="four.html">Page 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="five.html">Page 5</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Information</a></li>
   </ul>  
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
 
<div id="content" style="text-align:center;">
 <table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 20px;">
  <tr>
   <td align="center"> 
    This is main content div, indexed BEFORE my navigation.
   </td>  
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Been bugging me for weeks, probably an easy fix, but can't think of one. Any input is welcome...  Hope someone knows how to sort this annoying problem :P

Comment: remove `.nav {
    left: 60%;`  it's work fine

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
/*gradient behind the navigation*/
#nav_grad {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffff00, #CCCC00); 
 position:absolute; 
 left:0%; 
 top:0%; 
 height:70px; 
 width:100%; 
 z-index:0; 
}

/*Navigation is indexed to be infront of background and the main content above^^^*/
.nav { 
 position: relative;
left: 60%;
top: 20%;
float: left;
width: 40%;
}

/*Removes margins and padding*/
ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
display: flex;
width: 100%;
}

/*nav bar design*/
ul li {
 float: left; 
 width: inherit; 
 height: 40px; 
 opacity: 0.9; 
 line-height: 40px; 
 text-align: center; 
 font-size: 90%; 
 padding-right: 3%;
 padding-left: 3%;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
}
ul li ul{
 display: block;
}
/*links design for nav bar*/
ul li a {
 text-decoration: none; 
 color: black;
 font-style: bold;
 font-weight: 800;
 display: block;
}
/*Text of drop navigation when you hover hover*/
ul li a:hover {
 color:#999999;
 opacity:1;
}

/*by default nothing will be displayed until you hover*/
ul li ul li{
 display: none;
}

/*Drop down when you hover*/
ul li:hover ul li {
 display: block;
 margin-left: -20%;
 width: 140%;
 background-color: #5555ff;
}

/*prevents overflow (WELL MEANT TO)*/
.nav_container {
 width:100%;
 height:70px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

/*When I hover the idea is to make the div so drop down can be seen on Y axis, still keeping overflow on the x*/
.nav_container:hover {
 height:100%;
}

/*creates a div in the center of the screen for all the content, indexed to be behind navigation bar but in front of the background*/
#content { 
 position:absolute; 
 left:25%; 
 top:15%; 
 height:84.4%; 
 width:50%; 
 background-color: #ffffff; 
 border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
 z-index:-1; 
 overflow: auto;
}

/*If screen is under 860 pixels below will happen*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 860px){
  .nav {
   position:relative;
  left:55%;
  top:20%;
  }
 
 ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -40%;
  width: 180%;
  background-color: #5555ff;
 }
    
  #nav_grad {
    background: linear-gradient(#ffff00, #CCCC00); 
   position:absolute; 
   left:0%; 
   top:0%; 
   height:50px; 
   width:100%; 
   z-index:0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="nav_container"> <!--Here is the div that should control drop down list overflow-->

 <!--Linear gradient div is behind navigation-->
 <div id="nav_grad" style="text-align:center;">
  <!--navigation-->
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="">Hover</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="one.html">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="two.html">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="three.html">Page 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="four.html">Page 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="five.html">Page 5</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Information</a></li>
   </ul>  
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
 
<div id="content" style="text-align:center;">
 <table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 20px;">
  <tr>
   <td align="center"> 
    This is main content div, indexed BEFORE my navigation.
   </td>  
 </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `left:60%` from `nav class` which it make scroll for div

```
.nav { 
    position:relative;
    /*left:60%;*/
    left: 0;
    top:20%;
}
```

you can use `overflow hidden` for all the body

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*gradient behind the navigation*/
#nav_grad {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffff00, #CCCC00); 
    position:absolute; 
    left:0%; 
    top:0%; 
    height:70px; 
    width:100%; 
    z-index:0; 
}

/*Navigation is indexed to be infront of background and the main content above^^^*/
.nav { 
    position:relative;
    left:60%;
    top:20%;
}

/*Removes margins and padding*/
ul {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

/*nav bar design*/
ul li {
 float: left; 
 width: 7%; 
 height: 40px; 
 opacity: 0.9; 
 line-height: 40px; 
 text-align: center; 
 font-size: 90%; 
 padding-right: 3%;
 padding-left: 3%;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
}

/*links design for nav bar*/
ul li a {
 text-decoration: none; 
 color: black;
 font-style: bold;
 font-weight: 800;
 display: block;
}
/*Text of drop navigation when you hover hover*/
ul li a:hover {
 color:#999999;
 opacity:1;
}

/*by default nothing will be displayed until you hover*/
ul li ul li{
 display: none;
}

/*Drop down when you hover*/
ul li:hover ul li {
 display: block;
 margin-left: -20%;
 width: 140%;
 background-color: #5555ff;
}

/*prevents overflow (WELL MEANT TO)*/
.nav_container {
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

/*When I hover the idea is to make the div so drop down can be seen on Y axis, still keeping overflow on the x*/
.nav_container:hover {
    height:100%;
}

/*creates a div in the center of the screen for all the content, indexed to be behind navigation bar but in front of the background*/
#content { 
    position:absolute; 
    left:25%; 
    top:15%; 
    height:84.4%; 
    width:50%; 
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
    z-index:-1; 
    overflow: auto;
}

/*If screen is under 860 pixels below will happen*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 860px){
  .nav {
      position:absolute;
        left:40%;
        top:20%;
  }

    ul li {
 float: left; 
 width: 7%; 
 height: 40px; 
 opacity: 0.9; 
 line-height: 40px; 
 text-align: center; 
 font-size: 90%; 
 padding-right: 20%;

 list-style: none;
 margin: 0px;
}

    ul li:hover ul li {
        display: block;
        margin-left: -40%;
        width: 400%;
        background-color: #5555ff;
    }

  #nav_grad {
    background: linear-gradient(#ffff00, #CCCC00); 
      position:absolute; 
      left:0%; 
      top:0%; 
      height:50px; 
      width:100%; 
      z-index:0; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use then `position:absolute;` on the DIV where you are trying to limit your range of view which in your case would be `.nav_container{}` as everything comes with strings and nothing is that simple. You need to find a working combination for yourself. And no offense, but your styling makes absolutely no sense to me unless it's purely for testing purposes. Everything must have a proper order and you need to know when to use overflow and when not. You need to know when to use position absolute and when not. You need to know when to use a DIV and when to use a UL and LI. You need to know when to use a CLASS and when to use an ID. In your case everything looks so random.